# Error when connecting openxenmanager to xen-4.4

Tags: software-installation, connection, xen

Xen newbie question :
I've installed last ubuntu *xen* and *openxenmanager* on my Intel I5 64bit workstation with *default* configuration and after  rebooted on xen grub choice :

`cylere@lalla:~$` **ps -ef |grep xen**
`root        37     2  0 janv.16 ?      00:00:00 [xenwatch]
root        38     2  0 janv.16 ?      00:00:00 [xenbus]
root        46     2  0 janv.16 ?      00:00:00 [xenbus_frontend]
root      2443     1  0 janv.16 ?      00:00:00 /usr/lib/xen-4.4/bin/xenstored --pid-file=/var/run/xenstore.pid
root      2449     1  0 janv.16 ?      00:00:00 /usr/lib/xen-4.4/bin/xenconsoled --pid-file=/var/run/xenconsoled.pid
root      2456     1  0 janv.16 ?      00:00:00 /usr/bin/qemu-system-i386 -xen-domid 0 -xen-attach -name dom0 -nographic -M xenpv -daemonize -monitor /dev/null -serial <br>/dev/null -parallel /dev/null -pidfile /var/run/qemu-dom0.pid
cylere    4898  4848  0 00:03 pts/9    00:00:00 grep --color=auto xen
cylere@lalla:~$` **openxenmanager**
`http://lalla:80
 http://lalla:80`

I got in a popup : **`<ProtocolError  for lalla:80/RPC2: 404 Not Found>`**

- Is my server launched ?
- what parameters I've to transmit ?
- Am I wrong in my installation ?
- what is missing ?
- is documentation somewhere ?

`

Answer (score 2):

OpenXenManager (latest version on https://github.com/OpenXenManager/openxenmanager) is meant to be used with the Citrix XAPI stack. However, XAPI (and it's open implementation XCP-XAPI) are no longer supported on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS upward. The open source version of xen comes with the so-called "xl" stack, the official successor to "xm".

However, if you just want to use a graphical front end, try the virt-manager package:

```
apt-get install virt-manager libvirt0
```

Answer (score 0):

You use new Xen hypervisor (>=4.1). You need change toolstack, xl to xm && restart xend.

1.Replace default xl toolstack to xm:

```
echo "TOOLSTACK=xm" > /etc/default/xen
```

2.Check xend config http params ( if not exist -> create .xsp config):

```
nano /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp
..
(xend-http-server yes)
(xend-port            80)
...
```

3.Restart xend:

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/xend restart
```

4.Check http port:

```
 netstat -antup|grep 80
```

P.S. Downgrade toolstack - this is a bad idea but xm (xend) depricated:

http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XL

openxenmanager will not work with the newest 'box versions' of XL